# ¿Cómo obtener el promedio y máximos y mínimos de una tabla SQLite en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy haciendo una app que permita capturar el nombre y tres calificaciones. En base a las tres calificaciones obtengo el promedio, y difiero si esta aprobado o reprobado.

Estos datos los almaceno en una base de datos SQLite, campos: nombre, calificación uno, calificación dos, calificación tres, promedio, estado (Aprobado / reprobado).

No tengo problema para almacenar ni obtener todos los registros, el detalle ocurre al querer sacar el promedio general de todos los usuarios, y el mayor y menor.

El código es:

Crear base de datos:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB) {
    DB.execSQL("create Table alumnos(nombre TEXT, calfUno REAL, calfDos REAL, calfTres REAL, promedio REAL, aprobado TEXT)");
}
```

Insertar en la base de datos (Aquí calculo el promedio y estado del alumno):

```
    public boolean insertar (String nombre, double cu, double cd, double ct){
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    double prom = (cu+cd+ct)/3;
    cv.put("nombre", nombre);
    cv.put("calfuno", cu);
    cv.put("calfdos", cd);
    cv.put("calftres", ct);
    cv.put("promedio", prom);
    cv.put("aprobado",  prom>70.0 ? "aprobado" : "Reprobado" );
    long result = DB.insert("alumnos", null, cv);
    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Aquí obtengo los registros:

```
    public Cursor verInformacion(){
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from alumnos", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Aquí en teoría saco el promedio:

```
    public Cursor promedioGeneral (){
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor promedio = DB.rawQuery("select (AVG(promedio)) from alumnos", null);
    //String dato = promedio.toString();
    return promedio;
}
```

Y en un boton, recibo el "promedio":

```
                Cursor prom = DB.promedioGeneral();
            StringBuffer proma = new StringBuffer();
            proma.append(prom.getDouble(0));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, proma.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Ocurre que la aplicación se cierra y truena. Podrían ayudarme a ver como obtener el promedio general y como obtener el mayor y el menor?.

El error del logcat es:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested,
> with a size of 1

Error del stacktrace:

```
2021-09-28 03:43:20.133 18264-18264/com.example.promedioalumnos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.promedioalumnos, PID: 18264
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getDouble(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:86)
    at com.example.promedioalumnos.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

El metodo es:

```
            promedio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Cursor prom = DB.promedioGeneral();
                StringBuffer proma = new StringBuffer();
//Aqui esta el error, aqui abajo es la linea 55
                proma.append(prom.getDouble(0));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, proma.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías controlar el `LogCat`, ahí debe salir el porque se cierra la app

Comment: Tienes una idea de como hacer el promedio?
El error es este: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: Muestra más líneas del stacktrace hasta que sea vea qué método arrojó esa exception.

Comment: Listo, actualice el mensaje de error en la pregunta

Comment: O me podrian explicar directamente como hacer el promedio, y maximos y minimos?
nunca he tomado bases de datos, y es de mis primeras veces en Android

Comment: falta un `prom.moveToFirst();` antes de intentar leer el valor

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el promedio de los registros para el  campo `promedio`, usa la consulta:

```
select (AVG(promedio)) from alumnos
```

Para obtener el valor máximo de los registros para el  campo `promedio`, usa la consulta:

```
select (MAX(promedio)) from alumnos
```

Para obtener el valor minimo de los registros para el  campo `promedio`, usa la consulta:

```
select (MIN(promedio)) from alumnos
```

Con respecto a el error:

> .CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Cuando obtienes el cursor si los datos se obtuvieron en una consulta que arroja un solo valor posible (`"select (AVG(promedio)) from alumnos"`) entonces debes realizar lo siguiente:

```
   Cursor prom = DB.promedioGeneral();
   StringBuffer proma = new StringBuffer();

   if (prom.moveToFirst()) { 
       proma.append(prom.getDouble(0));
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, proma.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   prom.close();
```

muy importante siempre cerrar los cursores.